# Is there a way to hide my domain Whois information for free?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, whois, icann

I am so sick of being spammed by calls and emails every time I register a new domain name. I know I can pay for Whois protection with my domain name registrar, or choose a registrar who provides this as a benefit, but is there a way to protect my details for free without breaking ICANN Whois rules?

Answer (score 5):

Just wait until May 25 and then use a registrar in the EU. The new GDPR rules will prohibit making personal information publicly available with whois. See [here](https://domainnamewire.com/2017/08/17/gdpr-whois/), for example.

Answer (score 3):

There are domain registry services that allow for free private whois information. One of the registrars that I use doesn't charge me anything extra for private whois. One of the other registrars that I use charges me an arm and a leg for private whois.

I think it's largely dependent on which registrar you go with, as their pricing breakdown is most often how they base their profit model.

Answer (score 2):

Many Registrars, including us, will give you privacy for free.

There are also extensions where privacy is the default, not just an option.